# Auto Update Fails with error Not enough disk space available

Tags: updating, ee5

EE v5.2.2 -> v5.2.3
PHP 7.3

Not enough disk space available to complete the update ( free bytes reported). Please free up some space and try the upgrade again.

I've triple checked permissions, and everything looks OK.

I suspect that the testing function is not returning anything.
There is plenty of space available.
I've just tested with a basic php script, disk_free_space('/') returns 8736477184 while disk_free_space('.') returns nothing.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hacking getFreeDiskSpace function to return TRUE in ExpressionEngine/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Filesystem/Filesystem.php around line 596 allows the update to complete, but this is a temporary fix.

Comment: there are breaking bugs in EE5.2.3 (to do with relationship fields) so maybe just wait it out until 5.2.4?